# Изменение координат элемента внутри Canvas

Tags: wpf, c#

Для схематичного отображения движения элементов используется Canvas.

```
<Canvas Height="600" Width="800" x:Name="bCanvas" >
        <Ellipse x:Name="targetPoint"  Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Red"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="sourcePoint"  Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Black"/>
</Canvas>
```

Положение элемента задается с помощью `canvas.bottom` и `canvas.left`. Хотелось бы реализовать изменение координат элементов по таймеру.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике таймера тебе нужно установить свойства Canvas.Top и Canvas.Left c помощью методов [Canvas.SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx) и [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) для обоих эллипсов.